# Ruby: Mildly 'exotic' inheritance doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, methods, superclass

I would like to factor a bunch of common code from subclasses into a superclass method.  The superclass method must refer to a nonexistent (in the superclass) method that will be defined in the subclasses.  But I can't get this to work.

This is one try out of many multiple variations I have tried:

```
class Superclass
    def chunk_of_code
        # <code...>
        nonexistant_superclass_method_defined_in_subclass params
        # <more code...>
    end
end

class Subclass < Superclass
    def nonexistant_superclass_method_defined_in_subclass params
        # whatever...
    end
end

Subclass.new.chunk_of_code params
```

This doesn't work.  Other variations don't work either.  Is this kind of coding possible in Ruby (I thought it was)?  I did this kind of thing all the time working in Smalltalk.

Any way to achieve what I want?  Please avoid advising me to use "mix-ins" or "modules," as I'd just like to just learn and use Ruby's inheritance for right now.

*Running latest version of Ruby.

Thanks.

EDIT:  This is in a Rails app.  The superclass is ApplicationController.

EDIT:  Here is actual code from one of many iterations I've tried to do this.  This particular example craps out with "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" in the view, apparently because the whole thing is running in the context of the super (where it isn't defined) instead of the sub, or at least that's my interpretation:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    before_filter :authenticate_registration!

    # models and x defined in subclass
    def index
        models = x.where registration_id: current_registration.id

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: models }
        end
    end
    # more code here...
    # ...
end

class PositionsController < ApplicationController
    def x
        Position
    end

    def models= blah
        @positions = blah
    end

    # more code here...
    # ...
end
```

Comment: @Dave: Of course you can have an instance method that refers to another instance method that doesn't exist yet.. regarding the question: What exactly doesn't work? It works fine for me.

Comment: @NiklasB. Not sure what I was thinking there, but w/o knowing what behavior the OP is seeing, wasn't sure how to respond--hence I didn't answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is actually nothing to do with inheritance and is on this line

```
models = x.where registration_id: current_registration.id
```

This is potentially ambiguous: does this mean call the method `models=` or does it mean assign to a local variable called `models`? In this (and similar) situation ruby assumes you're trying to deal with the local variable. If you want to call the method instead you need to do

```
self.models = x.where registration_id: current_registration.id
```

Since you `models=` method doesn't get called, `@positions` is nil and I assume your view tries to use it.

You might also be interested in gems such as make_resourceful that handle this common controller stuff.

Comment: HOLY COW, that was it (sorry, serious ruby/rails newb here)!  Thanks so much!  Actually I had tried a bunch of "selfs" in other areas, i.e. self.x.where, and nothing worked.  Actually, the models= was not originally there either, it was added because other stuff wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

The only error you have here is the definition of the `chunk_of_code`. This method has to accept some formal parameter, like:

```
def chunk_of_code params
```

And then you're free to call it:

```
params = 'something'
Subclass.new.chunk_of_code params
```

Comment: @RG with these modifications your code runs w/o errors. I tried before answering.

Comment: But either way it doesn't work.  Perhaps I should add that this is in a Rails app?  The superclass is ApplicationController.  The subclasses are various specific controllers.  Is it possible that Rails screws up the inheritance mechanism?

Comment: @R.G. Yes, Rails does a lot of metaprogramming magic. I think you need to add more information and some of your own research to the question. In particular, you need a much better error description than "doesn't work".

Comment: "Doesn't work" takes many forms depending on what variation of "attempt" I'm attempting.  Most recent "doesn't work" is a method call against nil that blows up, because nil has been assigned to nonexistant_superclass_method_defined_in_subclass, because the method seems to be running in the context of the superclass (where it isn't defined) vs. the subclass where it is.  Might edit my post to add more information - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Over on the model side of Rails, I routinely use:

```
class GenericModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # define all the generic behavior methods/ model stubs you want.
  # model-specific classes can override to their hearts content
  # or use the inherited implementation

end

class Feature < GenericModel
  # model specific methods, and/or overrides
end
```

and I use a

```
class GenericController
  # basic show implementation for example
  def show
    @object = params[:controller].singularize.camelcase.constantize.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { render :layout => false }
      format.html  # show
      format.xml { render :xml => @object.to_xml }
    end
  end
end
```

If a specific model's show behavior isn't any different than generic, then that method doesn't appear in that 'model'_controller.rb.

Answer (score -1):

A way to do this is to define it in the parent and `raise NotImplementedError` as the behavior of the method.  By the way what you are trying to do is create an abstract class, which is facilitated more in certain other languages like Java.

Comment: Well, I believe you believe wrong. Also, recommending Java instead of Ruby is not very practical

Comment: @NiklasB. Nobody recommended Java, but Java has a specific mechanism for implementing abstract classes that Ruby doesn't. Ruby doesn't *need* it, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @NiklasB. Could you be a mite more specific?  Do you have a justification for believing that I'm wrong?

By the way I did not tell him to use Java, I pointed out that the concept he is dealing with is explicitly present there.

Comment: @TEOUltimus: You don't have to define it in the parent. That's where I think you're wrong and that's the reason I don't think this qualifies as an answer

Comment: @NiklasB. Edited, now I no longer claim that you "have to" define it in the parent.

Comment: @TEOUltimus: It still doesn't explain what the problem with OP's approach is. If the method is already present in the base class or not really doesn't matter. Probably an answer to the question would involve some analysis of the metaprogramming of Rails' controller base class.

Comment: He didn't even mention he was using rails until the most recent edit.

Comment: @TEO: You also don't answer the original question, because what OP wants to do is in fact very possible without any tricks.